# Dronekit android tower telemetry update frequency

Tags: dronekit, dronekit-android

I've just started looking into building something using dronekit. Before I dive headfirst into this (and I fully realize this might be a difficult question to answer): What kind of telemetry update frequency can I expect from the 3DR services underlying an android app (say that I'm using a PixHawk controller with the 3DR telemetry downlink plugged into my Android's USB port). I need something as instantaneous as possible, no slower than 1Hz and optimally down to 5-10Hz (talking about both telemetry update events from the drone, and the ability to send commands to the drone). Is it possible at all to get that kind of speed using this stack?

Answer (score 0):

Sending commands to the drone is not throttled at the moment, so it can be as fast as your logic and hardware allow.
The receiving update frequency is currently locked at 2Hz. We're looking into making it customizable in a future release.

For more information, feel free to ping the dev team directly on the [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/dronekit/dronekit-android).

Comment: ok thanks. So at the moment my only option is to use a Raspberry or similar onboard computer with a fast GPS directly connected and do telemetry exchange between the ground station and the onboard computer? I was hoping to avoid that. Configurable telemetrou output frequency from the pixhawk would be great.